# How to create numpy array element?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create 2d numpy array from generator function.
how to return the value as numpy array element so that I can create numpy array.

```
import numpy

def gen_num_py():
    yield [4287053, 19801222, 19881222]
    yield [4287054, 19801223, 19881223]
    yield [4287055, 19801224, 19881224]

a = numpy.fromiter(gen_num_py(), int)
```

this gives an erro (obviously)

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

the question is how to create numpy array element in yield statement so that this works to give result:

```
array([[4287053, 19801222, 19881222],
       [4287054, 19801223, 19881223],
       [4287055, 19801224, 19881224]])
```

Comment: but you are creating a numpy array...

Comment: I do not really get what you ask. In your question you demonstrate how to construct a numpy array...

Comment: @NilsWerner actually, this fails. The OP just didn't show the error message, I believe that was meant to be the *desired* output.